# Callback de reCaptcha quando usuario errar

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha, captcha

Existe alguma função do reCaptcha do google que é ativada quando o usuário erra as opções ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe.

Aqui você consegue ver a documentação dele.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

O que eu costumo usar é o `grecaptcha.getResponse` para saber se ele já validou ou não. Se validou ele retorna o token que será enviado ao servidor. Se não tiver validado ele é vazio.

Qual seria o motivo para precisar disso? Complementa a pergunta que eu complemento a resposta.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO:**

Segundo o raciocínio do comentário, eu desconheço uma função dele para isso, talvez um javascript pegando o foco de algum id ou classe do recaptcha.

Você pode tentar também o [invisível](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible):

tenho usado ele bastante e a experiencia para o usuário é bem legal.

Comment: Queremos saber os campos que a pessoa preencheu antes de entrar no desafio do captcha, para sabermos se ele está ou não impactando na quantidade de pessoas que preenchem o formulário.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: O grecaptcha.getResponse ajuda na hora de saber se foi validado ou não, e já utilizo o captcha invisivel. Vou tentar chamar uma função no onclick do botão de envio e utilizar o getresponse para ver se o token foi pego.